# Evaluate the definite integral of 3x(1-x^2)^5 dx from x =0 to x = 2

Tags: calculus

I know the answer is -182, but how do you work out this problem?? How in the world do you take the anti derivative of a function like that?

Comment: What techniques do you have available? Do you know what $u$-substitution is, or how to integrate powers of $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1-x^2)^5$=$x^{10} + 5x^8 + 10x^6 +10x^4 + 5x^2 + 1$

So $3x(1-x^2)=3x^{11}+15x^9+30x^7+30x^5+15x^3+3x$
Easy enough to integrate this polynomial

Comment: I knew you could do that, but I figured there was a shorter way

Answer (score 3):

Set $\displaystyle1-x^2=y\implies-2x\ dx=dy, x=0\implies y=1-0^2=1, x=2\implies y=-3$

$$\int_0^23x(1-x^2)^5\ dx=3\int_1^{-3}y^5\frac{(-dy)}2$$

Comment: Wait what? I have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: @Dylan, http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/substitution/substitution.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution